# Is it possible to filter rsyslog messages based on an environment variable, the content of a file or the output of a command?

Tags: rsyslog

I am configuring setup scripts for automatically created VMs which need to filter syslog messages in rsyslogd based on an environment variable.

I need to be able to change where logs get sent based on environment variable, the output of a command or the content of a file. Is this possible with rsyslog?